# Error after simple packages update of raspbian bulleyes: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal: 15: mv: not found

Tags: raspbian, kernel, update, failure

After did as usually commands `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` I am facing the following issue:

```
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 5.10.103+ /boot/kernel.img
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal:
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal: 15: mv: not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal exited with return code 127
dpkg: erreur de traitement du paquet raspberrypi-kernel (--configure) :
 installed raspberrypi-kernel package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: des problèmes de dépendances empêchent la configuration de libcamera0:armhf :
 libcamera0:armhf dépend de raspberrypi-kernel (>= 1:1.20211201~) ; cependant :
 Le paquet raspberrypi-kernel n'est pas encore configuré.

dpkg: erreur de traitement du paquet libcamera0:armhf (--configure) :
 problèmes de dépendances - laissé non configuré
dpkg: des problèmes de dépendances empêchent la configuration de libcamera-tools :
 libcamera-tools dépend de libcamera0 (>= 0~git20220303+e68e0f1e) ; cependant :
 Le paquet libcamera0:armhf n'est pas encore configuré.

dpkg: erreur de traitement du paquet libcamera-tools (--configure) :
 problèmes de dépendances - laissé non configuré
dpkg: des problèmes de dépendances empêchent la configuration de libcamera-apps :
 libcamera-apps dépend de libcamera0 (>= 0~git20220201+e96d0201) ; cependant :
 Le paquet libcamera0:armhf n'est pas encore configuré.

dpkg: erreur de traitement du paquet libcamera-apps (--configure) :
 problèmes de dépendances - laissé non configuré
Des erreurs ont été rencontrées pendant l'exécution :
 raspberrypi-kernel
 libcamera0:armhf
 libcamera-tools
 libcamera-apps
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

The error seems linked to the /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal script:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

eval $(apt-config shell APT_CONF_D Dir::Etc::parts/d)
test -n "${APT_CONF_D}" || APT_CONF_D="/etc/apt/apt.conf.d"
config_file="${APT_CONF_D}/01autoremove-kernels"

generateconfig() {
        cat <<EOF
// DO NOT EDIT! File autogenerated by $0
APT::LastInstalledKernel "$1";
EOF
}
generateconfig "$@" > "${config_file}.dpkg-new"
mv -f "${config_file}.dpkg-new" "$config_file"
chmod 444 "$config_file"
```

I already tried running: `sudo apt clean` and `sudo apt autoremove` without success.
Same with `sudo dpkg --configure -a`.

Does anyone can have an idea here?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be missing `mv`, a pretty basic Linux tool which is part of `coreutils` package.

First, check if you actually have `/bin/mv` - if you do, there's probably a problem with your `$PATH` variable. Unless you modified any config files, a reboot may help, though it may be risky in the middle of a kernel upgrade.

If you don't have `/bin/mv`, you could try to reinstall `coreutils`. If `apt` refuses to work, you have the option of manually downloading the package from http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/c/coreutils/ and extracting its contents with `ar -x`.